# IIS Virtual Directory Windows Authentication

Tags: iis

I have an intranet site with only Windows Authentication enabled, this works fine, users logged into windows can get onto the site without being prompted for a password.

I am trying to add a virtual directory so i can display files from another server on the network, let's say `\\server2\files` and mapping it to the alias `http://mysite/files`.

But unless i set the Path credentials to a Specific user, it just does not work - it prompts for a username and password repeatedly and refuses to accept valid credentials.

How can i get the main application to pass the windows credentials through to the virtual directory, or even accept valid credentials for that matter?

Comment: Which version of Windows/IIS?

Comment: @James It's Server 2016 with IIS 10.0

Comment: I don't have much experience with that version, but on Server 2008 R2, you set the Virtual Directory to connect as "Application user (pass-through authentication)", which is the default.  It sounds like either the ApplicationPoolIdentity (IIS APPPOOL\<PoolName>) user or the user you're accessing it with don't have access to the target folder.  I often have issues with the ApplicationPoolIdentity accessing folders--IIS seems to be very picky about where you create the folder and when you create it (relative to installing IIS and setting up the application).

Comment: You may just need to grant NTFS rights to the correct IIS APPPOOL\<AppName> user.

Comment: `Everyone` has access to the folder i am trying to map, it's fine if i map to a folder on the machine IIS is running on, but not to the file server. My application pool is running under a domain account that has access too, if i specify the virtual directory to use the same user as the application pool, that works..

Comment: These may be related...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5437723/iis-apppoolidentity-and-file-system-write-access-permissions and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22240439/granting-write-permissions-to-a-networked-unc-folder-for-asp-net-under-iis-7-5-a

Comment: @James i'm thinking it's a double hop issue, i have managed to get it working when the files are on the same server i'm serving the webpage from, hitting other issues now though, I will update if I find a decent fix