# IIS Virtual Directory - Hosting Remote Share and using Windows Auth

Tags: windows, iis, spn

The post linked ([IIS Virtual Directory Windows Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41873574/iis-virtual-directory-windows-authentication)) seems to have the same issue as me, but it was never resolved.

I have the following machines sitting on an active directory domain in my test lab:

- *WEB1*, an IIS web server on Windows. It has an alias, *ConfigMgt*
- *CONTENT1*, a content windows server that also happens to be an IIS web server. It has an alias, *ServiceMgt*
- *CLIENT1*, a windows 10

There is also a custom domain account *SERVICE-ACCT* that I use as the identity for the application pool.

CONTENT1 is configured to use *SERVICE-ACCT* for the identity of the application pool. The attribute *useAppPoolCredentials* is enabled at the website level for Windows Authentication and Windows Authentication is enabled.

WEB1 is also configured the same way as CONTENT1 in terms of the web server.

There are the following SPNs set for the service account *SERVICE-ACCT*:

```
HTTP/content1.domain
HTTP/content1
HTTP/web1.domain
HTTP/web1
```

These SPNs are set because WEB1 also acts as a proxy server for CONTENT1 for our python web applications through the Application Request Routing (ARR) module. As a result, it uses Negotiate for authenticating the python web applications.

With the context explained above, I created the virtual directory on WEB1 and called it "Example". The physical path is \\CONTENT1\Example and it is using pass-through authentication.

To access it, I go to *https://ConfigMgt.domain/Example* and I end up getting 401.3 errors when using *CLIENT1* logged in as a user that has access to \\CONTENT1\Example. If I set the physical path to \\WEB1\Example (after creating it) and move the contents of \\CONTENT1\Example to there, the authentication issues disappear.

I've verified that the identity of the application pool (*SERVICE-ACCT*) has access to the file share, \\CONTENT1\Example.

401.3 seems to refer to ACL type errors. I tried adding the *Everyone* group to the \\CONTENT1\Example share at both the share and NTFS permissions level but I had no success when I tried accessing the virtual directory again.

I am at a loss here. My goal is to host any remote network shares (ie. not local to WEB1) in virtual directories on WEB1; I also want to leverage the existing share/NTFS permissions that are set on those said shares. Is this possible?

Comment: This looks like a double-hop issue. In Active Directory, you may need to configure SERVICE-ACCT as a delegable account. Delegation allows the intermediary server to request other resources on behalf of the user without requiring the user's clear text credentials. In Windows environments, a common method of delegation is through the use of the Kerberos protocol for authentication and ticket delivery.

Comment: @YurongDai I have already enabled "Trust this user for delegation to any service (Kerberos only)" for SERVICE-ACCT in its AD user object settings. Strangely enough, I'm able to host Python Flask web applications from remote network shares... I just can't do it for virtual directories.

Comment: Virtual directories may involve access to remote shared resources, which may cause double-hop issues.
The user account needs to be configured to allow delegation so that the intermediary server can initiate third-party requests on the user's behalf. The intermediary server's computer account or service account needs to be configured as delegable so that it can continue the second hop on behalf of the user. Overall, double-hop is a complex issue and requires ensuring that all relevant components are properly configured for delegation and follow best security practices.